# SQL query using cast/convert in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I was recently writing a query where I had to convert a timestamp into a date and then perform aggregation on the converted date. Hence, a trivial way was to use the conversion formula in group by (same as while creating the column) and it did work.

However, it just did not seem to be the most optimized way. I could feel the performance deteriorating. Is there a better way to do it?

Query was using a view and was structured as follows:

```
SELECT  ORG ,
        CONVERT(DATE, CREATION_DATE, 101) ,
        SKU_CODE ,
        SKU_NAME ,
        COUNT(UNIT) AS Production
FROM    dbo.abcd_efgh_ijk(123, 'abc', NULL, '10009', NULL,
                          '2014-11-01 00:00:00', '2014-11-30 23:59:59') SFSTAT
WHERE   PASS_DATETIME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ORG ,
        SKU_CODE ,
        CONVERT(DATE, CREATION_DATE, 101) ,
        SKU_NAME
HAVING  COUNT(UNIT) >= 100;
```

Will be glad to learn an optimization here.

Comment: Looks like your `select columns list` are shorter version of `column names in group by` but it should be same

Comment: That was my bad, they are same

Comment: May be you should tune your `Table Valued Function`

Comment: What does the table function look like?  I would second the suggestion to look there for performance improvements

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this cannot be done, but you can easily side-step the issue with a simple subquery:

```
SELECT  ORG ,
        CreationDate ,
        SKU_CODE ,
        SKU_NAME ,
        COUNT(UNIT) AS Production
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ORG ,
        CONVERT(DATE, CREATION_DATE, 101) AS CreationDate,
        SKU_CODE ,
        SKU_NAME ,
        UNIT,
        PASS_DATETIME,
    FROM 
    dbo.abcd_efgh_ijk(123, 'abc', NULL, '10009', NULL,
                          '2014-11-01 00:00:00', '2014-11-30 23:59:59')
    ) SNMFT
WHERE   PASS_DATETIME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ORG ,
        SKU_CODE ,
        CreationDate,
        SKU_NAME
HAVING  COUNT(UNIT) >= 100;
```